# How to solve a matrix equation involving Hadamard product (Markov Chains, Average First Passage Cost)

Tags: markov-chains, hadamard-product

I am trying to find the average first passage cost of transition from $i$ to $j$ in a Markov Chain. If we consider costs of transitions as C[i,j], with the obvious property that $C[j,j]=0$, then we can calculate the costs as the expected value of the cost as a random variable for two cases, either a direct transition or an indirect transition, resulting in the following recurrence equation:

$C[i,j]=P[i,j](C[i,j]+C[j,j])+\sum_{k\in[0,n)|k\neq j}{P[i,k](C[i,k]+C[k,j])}$

where $P[i,j]$ is the transition probability from the Markov chain in question and the $C[i,j]$ is the average first passage cost that we are after. 
Then, considering the similarity of the two terms, and that $C[j,j]=0$, we unite the some as follows:

$C[i,j]=\sum_{k\in[0,n)}{P[i,k](C[i,k]+C[k,j])}=\sum_{k\in[0,n)}{(P[i,k]C[i,k]+P[i,k]C[k,j])}$

Which in matrix form can be vectorized as:

$\mathbf{C}=(\mathbf{P}\circ\mathbf{C})\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}\mathbf{C}$

I would like to find a closed-form solution by solving this matrix equation but do not know how to go further to bring all unknowns to one side.

Comment: Translating the summation to matrix form yields
$${C = {\rm diag}\big(CP^T\big){\tt\large 1}^T + PC}$$
without any Hadamard products.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, I see that $CP^T[i,i]=C[i,k]P[i,k]$ but I don't understand how a diagonal matrix of shape $n\times n$ multiplied by a row vector of shape $1\times n$ can be added to a matrix of shape $n\times n$.

Comment: Actually ${\rm diag}(M)$ returns the diagonal of the matrix argument as a column vector, so it's not a diagonal matrix. It's just a different way of writing the result you already have, but without the Hadamard product.

Comment: thanks for your explanation! Very smart indeed. As a teacher, however, I wonder if there is any resource you could kindly introduce for learning about such 'vectorization' procedures (is this the right term BTW?), i.e. is this an art or a methodical process? I see there is definitely 'experience' at play but are there also rules to follow?